# find center points/ segment white blobs in binary images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

[image]

In the shown image, I need to find the center points of the white blobs or I need to segment each white blob (to get an image which only contains that blob) from the background. 
What is the efficient way to do it?

Comment: Related: [Image Segmentation Tutorial ("BlobsDemo")](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25157-image-segmentation-tutorial-blobsdemo).

Comment: use `regionprops` and `bwlabel`

Comment: I tried just dilation,erosion and convolution with small circular elements..

Comment: Thanks. perfect. regionprops works fine. If you post your answer I can select it as a best answer.

Comment: @user570593 I would be interested in getting to know how you solved for the connected blobs. Did regionprops really do the job? What was the deciding step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is what exactly you are looking for: [Image Segmentation Tutorial ("BlobsDemo")](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25157-image-segmentation-tutorial-blobsdemo).

It contains demo to illustrate simple blob detection, measurement, and filtering. First it finds all the objects, then filters results to pick out objects of certain sizes. The basic concepts of **thresholding**, **labeling**, and **regionprops** are demonstrated with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use watershed algoritm for segmentation.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html

After segment cells use regionprops function.